# Phabricator installation issue

Tags: phabricator

I'm following the installation steps: http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Configuration_Guide.html, but can't install Phabricator successfully. Even I've checked the steps many times.

I created a folder in /tmp/codereview and in this folder, I downloaded the latest code from Github as below:

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Oct 31 16:28 arcanist
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Oct 31 16:28 libphutil
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Oct 31 17:23 phabricator
```

I also set the env. variable as just the manual indicated:

```
$export PHABRICATOR_ENV=/tmp/codereview/phabricator/conf/my
```

'my' acutally means 'my.conf.php', I've put the MySQL info in it. but when I execute the first setup command:

```
$./phabricator/bin/storage upgrade
```

I got the follow error messages:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/tmp/codereview/scripts/__init_script__.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /tmp/codereview/phabricator/bin/storage on line 21
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/tmp/codereview/scripts/__init_script__.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /tmp/codereview/phabricator/bin/storage on line 21
```

I think this is from Facebook and a lot of users are downloading it and using it. so the installation should work, do I miss something important?

If you have installed it successfully, can you help check what's wrong with my steps? if you use some previous release, what's your number, so I could use your release instead. Thanks.

Comment: For windows you can find details here: http://autoqainfo.blogspot.in/2014/09/phabricator-setup-on-windows-it-works.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved. this is due to the symbolic link. After I pulled the source code from github, I transferred(scp) the folder to another server where I'd like to install Phabricator. The symbolic will be replaced with real files. this will cause errors as I mentioned above.

So don't copy the folder directly to other server, you could package it and copy the tar ball.

Comment: Awesome!  I always just pull the git repos in on each server I set it up on - mostly because it becomes really easy to update it by just `pull`ing in changes.

Comment: This answer solved my issue! Not all server environment has Internet access so this is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I unsuccessfully attempted to install it the first time on a(n old) Debian system. I couldn't get it working and didn't end up figuring out what the problem was. On my second attempt:

- I created a brand new, empty Ubuntu VM from the latest Ubuntu release (version ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64).
- Downloaded the [Ubuntu installer script off from the Phabricator website](http://www.phabricator.com/rsrc/install/install_ubuntu.sh) and ran it on my VM.
- Once the above script was complete, configured the system as described in the [Phabricator installation guide](http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Installation_Guide.html).

This process worked very smoothly for me and I was up and running with it in no time! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try `PHABRICATOR_ENV=my`.  Unless they've changed something, it should just be relative, not absolute.

Comment: I've tried it, the same result. According to the error message and the source code of 'storage', the PHP has not reached the portion reading the env. variable.

Comment: I guessed the developers checked in a not-working-release. If someone has installed it successfully, I could pull his version, at least I could use it and wait for the developer to fix it.